# How to replace the space between words "alone" in a cell in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in excel (a sample cell is shown below):

```
               ABCD PQRS;Plate;00;2 XYZ MNO;Bracket;02,1
```

I wish to replace the **space between the words alone** with an underscore and **not any other space** in the cell using excel VBA, i.e.

```
            ABCD_PQRS;Plate;00;2 XYZ_MNO;Bracket;02,1
```

I tried finding a solution from various sources, but was not successful in finding what I need. Many suggested using

```
             =SUBSTITUTE and Replace(str, "", "_")
```

but either of them actually replaces all the spaces, even between numbers & words and/or numbers & numbers. 
I strictly need only the spaces between the words to be replaced and not any other spaces.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with a excel VBA code for the problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub removeSpaces()  
Dim req As String  
Range("$C$1").Activate  
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""  
    ActiveSheet.Select  
    '~~ code here to only choose spaces between words and ignore any other spaces
    req = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " ", "_")  
    ActiveCell.Value = req  
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate  
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I notice you have the Informed badge.  If you read the tour you would know that questions seeking a code answer should provide some code that you are having a problem with and explain the error codes or compile errors you are experiencing.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, but regular expressions will be best I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define what differentiates a **word** from a **not word**.  That definition is easily changed in the code below.  I chose to define **word** as a sequence that both begins and ends with a letter.  But other definitions can be substituted if this doesn't work:

**EDIT** Regex pattern and replacement codes altered to fix issue with sequential single character words.

```
Option Explicit
Function Underscore(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "([A-Za-z])\s+(?=[A-Za-z])"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True

    Underscore = .Replace(S, "$1_")
End With
End Function
```

Given the two examples you provided:

[image]

Comment: Yay!! Works without a flaw. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @JeevanSBalagam I edited the regex pattern and replacement code.  Although it works fine on the examples you gave, I noted some other instances in which it might fail.  Specifically, if there is a sequence such as X X X, it failed to put an underscore at the last spot.  The edited code takes care of that problem.

Comment: It works just fine. I have understood the difference, but my requirement doesn't need this particular change. Yet this is absolutely great. Thanks a lot for you time!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this custom function. See if it helps you

```
Function splitText(cellValue As Range)
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim newText As String
    arr = Split(cellValue.Text, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If i = UBound(arr) Then
            If (IsNumeric(Right(newText, 1)) Or IsNumeric(Left(arr(i), 1))) Then
                newText = newText & " " & arr(i)
            Else
                newText = newText & "_" & arr(i)
            End If
        Else
             If i = 0 Or (IsNumeric(Right(newText, 1)) Or IsNumeric(Left(arr(i), 1))) Then
                newText = newText & " " & arr(i)
            Else
                newText = newText & "_" & arr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    splitText = newText
End Function
```

Place the function in one excel cell, something like `=splitText(B4)` where B4 is the text you want to alter

Comment: It works partially. The code is not replacing all the required spaces. It however replaces a space between a number and word. Eg. RH MNT;NA;3;2 RH MNT;NA;3;2 15;FIREWALL is being changed to RH_MNT;NA;3;2_RH MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL instead of RH_MNT;NA;3;2 RH_MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL. I guess a slight improvement is required to the function to meet the requirement

Comment: Please edit the second if just like this: If i = 0 Or (IsNumeric(Right(newText, 1)) Or IsNumeric(Left(arr(i), 1))) Then

Comment: The "_" between 2 and RH is still there, although an "_" is now present between all words with spaces. The new result is like this:  RH_MNT;NA;3;2 _RH_MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL. ...;3;**2 _RH**_MNT.... This particular "_" (highlighted in ** **)should not be there. another small tweak in the function code I guess.

Comment: could you provide me the string that is not well transformed?

Comment: RH MNT;NA;3;2  RH MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL. This is my input. and the output so far is like:  RH_MNT;NA;3;2 _RH_MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL. Hope this helps.

Comment: and the desired output?

Comment: Running the code provided, the output is:  RH_MNT;NA;3;2 RH_MNT;NA;3;2 105;FIREWALL